# DolphinDB data type conversion issue

Tags: types, dolphindb

I ran into a problem with the following script:

```
id = id$symbol
```

where id is a string column. I got the following error message:

```
Please specify correct data type e.g. a$int (convert variable 'a' to integer type)
```

It's weird as I ran this line many times before and it went through, and I haven't updated DolphinDB database recently. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably defined the variable "symbol" somewhere before this script.

I can replicate your issue with the following script:

```
>id=`AA`BB`CC
>symbol=0;
>id$symbol;
Please specify correct data type e.g. a$int (convert variable 'a' to integer type)
```

So just check your code and avoid using words indicating data types as variable names.